# Test archive data (unzip -t equivalent) - Python

Tags: python, linux, unzip

I have a program written in python that uploads an archive (zip file) to a remote server. But before uploading it I need to test that it is not corrupted, so I want to execute something like an `unzip -t` and throw an error if it fails.

Is there something implemented in python that can do that (couldn't find anything on google), or is there a way to catch the error from my program if I execute the system call `unzip -t`?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Zipfile.testzip`](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.testzip) is your friend.

> Read all the files in the archive and check their CRC’s and file headers. Return the name of the first bad file, or else return None.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`ZipFile.testzip`](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.testzip):

```
import zipfile
def zip_isOk(fn):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(fn, 'r') as zipf:
        return zipf.testzip() is None
```